# How to write custom output to CSV from Powershell?

Tags: powershell, csv, scripting, identity

So I'm brand new to PowerShell and have been tasked with creating scripts to better manage user accounts in our environment. I wrote the below script (probably very poorly) that expires inactive accounts, moves them to a 'disabled' OU and spits out a CSV with certain user properties. What I would like to do is add a line that will write something like "no users found" in the CSV if the script runs and no inactive accounts are found. Googling has proved fruitless so far, so any input would be helpful. Thanks!

```
#EXPIRES INACTIVE ACCOUNTS AND MOVES THEM TO DISABLED OU

#Today's Date
$today=get-date -uformat "%Y/%m/%d"

#Date to search by
$time=(get-date).AddDays(-730)

#Expiration date
$expire=(get-date).AddDays(-1)

#Set variable for accounts to expire
$users=Get-ADUser -SearchBase 'OU=myusers,DC=mydomain,DC=com' -filter   {(Passwordlastset -lt $time) -and (lastlogondate -lt $time)} |` 
? {$_.Distinguishedname -notlike '*OU=Disabled*'}

#Sets CSV Path
$csvFilePath="\\myfilepath\mylogs\Disabled $(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd).csv"

$users | Foreach-object {get-ADUser -identity $_ -properties *} |select name, samaccountname, employeeid, Description |`
Export-Csv $csvFilePath -NoTypeInformation

#Changes Description to disabled - dateDisabled
$userDesc= "Disabled Inactive" + " - " + $today

$users | Set-ADUser -AccountExpirationDate $expire -Description $userdesc
$users | move-adobject -targetpath 'OU=Disabled,OU=myusers,DC=mydomain,DC=com'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the script is functional than its fine. You shouldnt need to change much of anything. Yes the code could be made more efficient but the end result would still be the same.

For what you are asking you would just need to get the count from `$users` and have an if statement just after  the line `$users = ...`

```
If ((Measure-Object -InputObject $users).Count -gt 0){
    #Process Code Here
} Else {
     "No users found with criteria used." | Out-File -FilePath $csvFilePath -Append  
}
```

`Measure-Object` will provide details of the input object passed. In our case `$users`. Measure-Object can return multiple values. We are only interested in `.Count`

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, this appears to be exactly what I was looking for.